# What function returning another function with parameters declared also as constants exactly do?

Tags: javascript, function, redux, closures, reselect

I'm completely lost. Below is a short code from an [article](https://medium.com/@pearlmcphee/selectors-react-redux-reselect-9ab984688dd4) considering Reselect library:

```
const shopItemsSelector = state => state.shop.items
const taxPercentSelector = state => state.shop.taxPercent

const subtotalSelector = state => {
  const items = shopItems(state)
  return items => items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0)
}

const taxSelector = state => {
  const subtotal = subtotalSelector(state)
  const taxPercent = taxPercentSelector(state)
  return (subtotal, taxPercent) => subtotal * (taxPercent / 100)
}

export const totalSelector = state => {
  const subtotal = subtotalSelector(state)
  const tax = taxSelector(state)
  return (subtotal, tax) => ({ total: subtotal + tax })
}
```

Can someone explain what function **totalSelector** returns?

I see it returns another function with parameters **subtotal** and **tax**, but why there are constants with the same names declared and how they correspond to the parameters of returned function?

Comment: if the function returned by totalSelector doesnt have any params, its going to create a closure with those 2 constants, but here they don't do anything

Comment: It's not *you* who's confused. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain what function `totalSelector` returns?

Almost certainly not what the author meant it to return. :-)

What it returns is a function that, when called with two arguments, returns an object with a `total` property that's the sum of the two arguments passed in. Everything in `totalSelector` *before* the `return` line is completely pointless and ignored, because the author has *shadowed* the `subtotal` and `tax` constants with parameters in the arrow function it's returning:

```
export const totalSelector = state => {
  const subtotal = subtotalSelector(state) // <=== These
  const tax = taxSelector(state)           // <=== constants
  //      vvvvvvvvvvvvv------------ are shadowed by these parameter declarations
  return (subtotal, tax) => ({ total: subtotal + tax })
  //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- so this uses the parameters
}
```

So the `subtotal` and `tax` in the arrow function's body are the parameters, not the constants.

The author probably meant to do this:

```
export const totalSelector = state => {
  const subtotal = subtotalSelector(state)
  const tax = taxSelector(state)
  return () => ({ total: subtotal() + tax() })
  //     ^^                      ^^      ^^
}
```

...though it's hard to be sure. That accepts a state object and returns a function that, when called, will select the subtotal and tax *as of that call* and return a total. Note that it accepts no parameters, and *calls* the functions it created via `subtotalSelector(state)` and `taxSelector(state)`.

`subtotalSelector` and `taxSelector` have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

`totalSelector()` returns a Function which expects two parameters `subtotal` and `tax`.

This `returned function` returns an `object with the property total` which is calculated through `subtotal + tax`

The constants declared have nothing to do with the function returned.

Comment: I did not downvote. But I guess that question author is confused with const declarations in selector, and you skipped this part in your explanation

Comment: @Andrey I see what you mean. Edited 2 mins after posting it tho. But thanks for the explanation :)